# How to prevent a table cell from having a line break in CSS?

Tags: html, css

I have an HTML document with some tables like this:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            term
        </td>
        <td>
            this is a definition
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

This appears like this:

```
 _____________________________
| term | this is a definition |
|______|______________________|
```

When I type a two-word word, such as "Web browser" in the first column, this is the result:

```
 _____________________________
| Web     | a tool for using  |
| browser | the WWW           |
|_________|___________________|
```

How can I adjust this behavior in CSS such that the first column only gets line breaks when the content is longer than 50% of the table width?

Ideally, the term in the left cell should never have a line break:

```
 _____________________________
| Web browser | a tool for    |
|             | using the WWW |
|_____________|_______________|
```

If the term in the left cell is really long though, e.g. exceed 50% of the width of the table, then a line break is okay:

```
 _____________________________
| this is a long | .......... |        
| term           | .......... |
|________________|____________|
```

How can this be done in CSS?

Comment: Did you tried `table-layout: fixed` ? http://jsfiddle.net/mr_alien/vSQ5N/

Answer (score 5):

do it this way

```
 html,body,table{
    width:100%;
    height:100%
 }
 tr > td:first-child{
    white-space:nowrap;
    max-width:50%;
    word-break:break-all;
 }
```

Comment: You'd need to add a class to every first td to target the nowrap to just the left column or add a :nth-child() parameter to your css. Yep never mind, fixed in edit.

Comment: @WBOCo. : ....your comment and my edit came at same time...+1 to your comment though!! :)

Answer (score 1):

I tried it with percentages like NoobEditor suggested but didn't see the results it sounds like you're looking for.

So if you can use pixels instead of percentages something like the following should work:

```
table{
    width:500px;
}
td:nth-child(odd) {
    max-width:250px;
}
td:nth-child(even) {
    min-width:250px;
}
```